# Redeclaration of static variables in C... never happens?

Tags: c, variables, static

I'm trying to fully understand how static variables work in C. I understand that using the static keyword makes the lifetime of the variable equal to the duration of the program. The following example has one thing that confuses me though...

My **static_test.c** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(){
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    printf("This function has been called %i times.\n",counter);
    return;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
         foo();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I first read this example it makes me wonder why the function doesn't print out 0 every time since we are assigning 0 to the static variable.

Is this because once a static variable is declared the compiler ignores another declaration of the same variable on the next calls to my `foo()` function?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is **the** purpose of `static`...

Comment: Also, initialization is not assignment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program

Comment: Nobody is assigning anything.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the use of `=`, this is an initialization, NOT an assignment.  So it happens when the variable is initialized and not when the 'statement' is apparently 'executed'.  Since it is a static variable, it is initialized once when the program starts, rather than every time the function runs.

Comment: Thank you!  I guess my mistake was in not understanding the difference between initialization and assignment.  Read up on the differences and now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are initialized exactly once at program start, before your function is ever called.  The fact that it's a local variable doesn't affect this rule.

In addition, static storage class variables are automatically initialized to zero if not explicitly initialized; the `= 0` in your program is superfluous.

From the C11 drafts standard (ISO/IEC 9899:201x), section **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**, paragraph 3:

> An object whose identifier is declared … with the storage-class specifier **`static`** has *static storage duration*. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Comment: "automatically initialized to zero, even if there's no explicit initializer" makes it seem that `i` in `static int i = 42;` will be initialized to 0 instead of 42.

Comment: But there *is* an explicit initializer in that statement.

Comment: I know that - but your statement implies that zero initialization applies to everything regardless.

Comment: So you just don't like the "even", or what?  You have plenty of rep to make an edit if you'd like.

Comment: Done. I saw the answer rapidly updating, and didn't want to step on your toes with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the compiler looks for an initial assignment after declaring a static variable and only executes it once, when the program starts.

This only happens when you declare the variable though. For example,

```
void foo(){
    static int counter;
    counter = 0;
    counter++;
    printf("This function has been called %i times.\n",counter);
    return;
}
```

Would print `1` every time.

Comment: The initialization in a declaration is **not** an assignment. People may be mislead by the `=` token, but it is part of initialization syntax and is distinct from the `=` operator in an assignment. Declaration statements have initialization. Expression statements have assignment. So the compiler does not “look for an initial assignment”.

Answer (score 0):

Static means the variable exists outside of the life time of the function. Think of it as a slightly clever global variable.